# if statement not executing

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

```
for(int i=0;i<number.length();i++){
    if(number.charAt(i)==0){
      nums[i]=11;
      System.out.println("bob");
    }else{
    nums[i]=number.charAt(i);
  }
  }
```

I am trying to get all 0 values to equal 11 in the array of nums and print bob every time it does that but for some reason the first if statement doesnt seem to be executing even when charAt(i) equals 0. Could someone please explain what is wrong?

Comment: Ok, so I get that I have to put '0' but now I want that nums element to equal 11 and nums is a char array but whenever I put nums[i]='11'; I get an unclosed character literal error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a string don't you mean  `if (number.charAt(i) == '0')` ?

Comment: Oh man thank you, i have been literally scratching my head for 3 hours because of this mistake

Comment: hmm so, if i was to put nums[i]='11'  would it make that nums element equal 11?

Comment: No, strings are immutable and CANNOT be edited, you must create a new string as String newString = nums[0] + "11" + nums.substring(2);

Comment: But nums isnt a string array it is a char array.

Comment: Oh, in that case you can only do nums[1] = '1', you can only have a single character per slot so if you want "11" you have to change nums[1] to '1' and nums[2] to '1'

Answer (score 4):

You should ask:

```
if (number.charAt(i)=='0')
```

Because the number 0 is different from the character '0', and you're interested in the character.

Answer (score 1):

try :
    if(number.charAt(i)=='0').
you compared int and char my mistake.